# SELECT CASE vs. CASE IN SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I do not quite understand why those two different codesamples return a different value.

somehow incorrect but working syntax, returns false results, e.g it returns `0` when the comparison is done over **two equal** values:

```
(SELECT CASE 
    WHEN 
       SUM(V.IsCompatible) OVER 
          (PARTITION BY ComputerName, UserID) = ApplicationCount 
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
) AS CompatibleUser
```

The one below returns the **correct values**, ie. `1` when there are **two equal values** compared.

```
(CASE 
    WHEN 
       SUM(V.IsCompatible) OVER 
         (PARTITION BY ComputerName, UserID) = ApplicationCount 
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
) AS CompatibleUser
```

or even simpler:

```
(SELECT CASE 
    WHEN 
       X = Y 
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
) AS Result
```

*X = 22 AND Y = 22 => Result = 0*

```
(CASE 
    WHEN 
       X = Y 
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
) AS Result
```

*X = 22 AND Y = 22 => Result = 1*

I understand **applying the correct syntax** is important, and I am aware of the SELECT CASE syntax in T-SQL, but I do not understand how the **first code sample is evaluated** and delivering an unexpected result.

update: full query in it's context

```
select userapplication.username,
   computerdetails.computername,
   sum(userapplication.iscompatible) 
       over (partition by computerdetails.computername, 
                          userapplication.userid) as compatiblecount,
   userapplication.applicationcount,
   ( case
       when sum(userapplication.iscompatible) 
           over (partition by 
           computerdetails.computername, 
           userapplication.userid) <> userapplication.applicationcount 
       then 0
       else 1
     end 
   ) as usercomputeriscompatible
from   computerdetails
   right outer join usercomputer
     on computerdetails.computerid = usercomputer.computerid
   right outer join userapplication
     on usercomputer.gebruikerid = userapplication.userid
```

so `userComputerIsCompatible` is the result in question here

Comment: You may have to show more of your query. Are these samples being used in the `SELECT` clause, the `WHERE` clause, `HAVING` clause, somewhere else?

Comment: I added the query ( a bit modified in naming) but it represents how it works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the reason for this behavior is the next one: the expressions like `(SELECT ...)` are considered to be sub-queries even they don't have `FROM` clause. Is assume the source of data for these (false) "sub-queries" is only the *current row*. So, `(SELECT expression)` is interpreted as `(SELECT expression FROM current_row)` and `(SELECT SUM(iscompatible)OVER(...))` is executed as `(SELECT SUM(iscompatible)OVER(current_row))`.

Argument: analyzing execution plan for `(SELECT SUM(IsWeb) OVER(PARTITION BY OrderDate) [FROM current_row])` expression
[image]

I see a [`Constant Scan` (Scan an internal table of constants)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188318%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx) operator instead of `Clustered Index Scan` before `Segment` and `Stream Aggregate` (`[Expr1007] = Scalar Operator(SUM(@OrderHeader.[IsWeb] as [h].[IsWeb]))`) operators. This internal table (`Constant Scan`) is constructed from current row.

Example (tested with SQL2005SP3 and SQL2008):

```
DECLARE @OrderHeader TABLE
(
     OrderHeaderID  INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
    ,OrderDate      DATETIME NOT NULL
    ,IsWeb          TINYINT NOT NULL --or BIT
);
INSERT  @OrderHeader 
SELECT  '20110101', 0
UNION ALL 
SELECT  '20110101', 1
UNION ALL
SELECT  '20110101', 1
UNION ALL 
SELECT  '20110102', 1
UNION ALL
SELECT  '20110103', 0
UNION ALL
SELECT  '20110103', 0;

SELECT  *
        ,SUM(IsWeb) OVER(PARTITION BY OrderDate) SumExpression_1
FROM    @OrderHeader h
ORDER BY h.OrderDate;

SELECT  *
        ,(SELECT SUM(IsWeb) OVER(PARTITION BY OrderDate)) SumWithSubquery_2
FROM    @OrderHeader h
ORDER BY h.OrderDate;
```

Results:

```
OrderHeaderID OrderDate               IsWeb SumExpression_1
------------- ----------------------- ----- ---------------
1             2011-01-01 00:00:00.000 0     2
2             2011-01-01 00:00:00.000 1     2
3             2011-01-01 00:00:00.000 1     2
4             2011-01-02 00:00:00.000 1     1
5             2011-01-03 00:00:00.000 0     0
6             2011-01-03 00:00:00.000 0     0

OrderHeaderID OrderDate               IsWeb SumWithSubquery_2
------------- ----------------------- ----- -----------------
1             2011-01-01 00:00:00.000 0     0
2             2011-01-01 00:00:00.000 1     1
3             2011-01-01 00:00:00.000 1     1
4             2011-01-02 00:00:00.000 1     1
5             2011-01-03 00:00:00.000 0     0
6             2011-01-03 00:00:00.000 0     0
```

Comment: +1 Agree, the `SELECT SUM(IsWeb) OVER(PARTITION BY OrderDate)` is clearly just being applied to the columns of the current row so will always have whatever the value of `IsWeb` is in that row.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and I get the same results for both queries. Here's the code I tried:

```
DECLARE @X INT = 22
DECLARE @Y INT = 22

SELECT (SELECT CASE 
    WHEN 
       @X = @Y 
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
) AS Result

SELECT (CASE 
    WHEN 
       @X = @Y 
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
) AS Result
```

Result is **1** and **1**

I ran this on SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: +1: Done the same myself and results are indeed equal and **correct**.

Comment: In my opinion the real problem is not `CASE ... END` but how `SUM(V.IsCompatible)` is computed in these two cases: `(SELECT SUM... no_FROM_clause)` and `(SUM...)`.